# List all groups on machine via bash script

Tags: linux, bash, debian

```
#!/bin/bash
GROUPS=$(cut -d: -f1 /etc/group)
echo "$GROUPS"
```

This code gives me an output of 1000 if I'm a regular user or 0 if I'm root, while executing the same command (`cut -d: -f1 /etc/group`) returns a list of all the available groups on the machine. I also tried with `grep "" /etc/group` but that produces the same results. What am I not getting here?

Comment: Note `$GROUPS` is an internal variable containing some information already

Comment: Why capture this content into a variable at all? If you just ran the command without any redirection the content would go straight to stdout, exactly where `echo` sends it. (But if you *are* going to capture into a variable, use a lower-case name to avoid collisions with variables having meaning to the shell or operating system).

Comment: Thanks for the answers you provided in these comments guys. I do not really need to capture it to a variable, but I initialized a lot of other vars at the same time and thought they should go together so the code looks more neat. I'll use lowercase from now on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proper way is `getent group|cut -d: -f1`, because there are some more authentication method than /etc/group. e.g. sql, ldap, etc...
And it is not recommended to use capitalized variable names in shellscript - exactly to prevent this.